# Auto download mpdf generated pdf document

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am newbie for mpdf so don't mind if you feel this question is stupid one:),

I generated the pdf document usinf mPDF class , the issue is that after pdf generated the browser opens it in tab . But i want it not to open but auto download , My code is like follwing..

```
include("../mpdf.php");
$html="my HTML code here !";

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf');
```

I am expecting that there will be a function to download in the mpdf class like `$mpdf->download` instead `$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf')`.I searched alot for this type solution but in vain i could't find any .

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Add 'D' parameter for download

```
$mpdf->Output('MyPDF.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Edited, it is an `download` parameter, use D

Comment: In their DOCS and Source, `I` is for browser output, `F` is for local save, `S` is to return as string and `D` is for download.

Comment: Mihai ,how can we do print on button click ? is there any parameter for it or if you can tell another method?

Comment: as we generate it i want that it directly go for print as well.

Comment: That is not HTML, you have 2 possible options, let the browser display it, or force-download. No direct print ..

Comment: Thank you. This was easy helpful.

Answer (score 13):

for downloading use this

```
$filename = "mpdf.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
   header('Content-type: application/force-download');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
   readfile($filename);
}
```

Comment: well i think you shud accept Mihai's answer as his ans is appropriate according to your ques

Comment: yes Milhai's second answer is best for my question , i accepted that ,