# MPDF php downloader

Tags: php, pdf, download, mpdf

I have used **mpdf** for pdf creation. Now, I want to download the generated pdf file to my local machine.

I used below code for this.

```
$mpdf->Output('dummy.pdf', 'D');
```

But, its not working for me. Please help me

Comment: Have tried the forced header solution?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139204/auto-download-mpdf-generated-pdf-document

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto download mpdf generated pdf document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139204/auto-download-mpdf-generated-pdf-document)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', Path::FILE);

Or look at the documentation:
https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html

Hope this helps.