# MPDF that will have a print view in the browser not automatically options to download

Tags: html, codeigniter, mpdf

HI I have a working MPDF that generates a PDF from an html php file. The only problem I have is it automatically downloads the PDF file instead of showing a print PDF view in the browser. How can I achieve that?

So this is currently my MY_pdf.php file in the libraries.

```
include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

class MY_pdf {

  public $param;
  public $pdf;

  public function __construct($param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3')
  {
      $this->param =$param;
      $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
  }

  function AliasNbPages($alias='{nb}') {
  //Define an alias for total number of pages
  $this->aliasNbPg=$alias;
  }

  function getPageCount() {
  return count($this->pages);
  }
}
```

I assume this is just an extension in the libraries, so here is the main part in the controller where I call the MPDF.

**Controller:**

```
public function printmembers()
{
        $this->load->model('mdladmin');
        $data['mem'] = $this->mdladmin->get_members();

        $html=$this->load->view('printmembersmasterlist', $data, true);

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('MY_pdf');

        //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->my_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        //download it.
        $this->my_pdf->pdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: did you check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139204/auto-download-mpdf-generated-pdf-document?rq=1

Comment: Thanks haven't tried it